# Oracle Procedure Slowness (Operation Time out error)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper

We have an oracle procedure which is inside a package. When we are calling that Procedure from .NET (Windows Forms) it is giving Operation timeout errors
After seeing this message "Operation Timeout Error" from the screen,when i go to SqlDeveloper and Compile All Packages then after compiling them, the procedure works very fast and i can retrieve the data in 5 seconds.
Can you anyone tell how to solve this issue and what is the root cause?

Comment: Did you try another Procedure on. Net

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352300/use-gvsession-to-tell-if-a-query-is-hanging

Answer (score 0):

Try this before run Procedure

```
ALTER PACKAGE yourpackage
   COMPILE PACKAGE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should proabbly analyse why package is getting invalid and need compilation before executing and either eliminate code taht causes invalidation or as previous answer says execute compile before running procedure.

Package can get invalid when you alter some dependent objects (swaping table names or synonyms during some load, altering table, dynamically droping and creating objects that package depends on). Those two threads may help you: [What Situations Cause Oracle Packages to Become Invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626267/what-situations-cause-oracle-packages-to-become-invalid) and [When does an Oracle Package Specification become INVALID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296088/when-an-oracle-package-specification-may-become-invalid) If you're able to eliminate package invalidation it is better if you can't go for compilation before each run of procedure.

One more cause that calling procedure from .NET is not recompiling package can be driver. I met such issue a few years ago and remember that changing driver helped. But I don't remember if we changed to managed or unamanged driver.